# Copying Clipboard from IDE and pasting on iPad while keeping color formatting

Tags: ipad, mac, copy-paste, formatting

I'm taking a course in java and I'm using my iPad to take notes (using the notability app). I wanted to know if there's any way to copy code I'd be writing on my Mac (IntelliJ IDE) to my iPad. It needs to be transferable quickly and easily so I can incorporate the code in my notes as a textbox in notability. The catch is, it also has to retain the text color so I can read it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a single great option for this because you can't copy directly into the clipboard of the iPad from the background, so in a sense you can't sync your clipboards.

However there is Pastebot which was quite good, it's a bit old now, but should work still.

Alternatively iCloud syncing through Notes.app is pretty fast.

Comment: But will either of these methods keep the color formatting? it's extremely hard to read code without it having the colors.

Comment: I didn't see that, no, but thats because the code highlighting is typically specific to the application and when you copy and paste it will normally only copy the plain text, not the formatting... If you want to copy it with formatting you'd need one that allows rich text copying (Arduino/Processing IDEs allow HTML or rich text).... This would be IDE dependent at this point and I am not sure whether Pastebot would support it, however Notes.app is basically just creating draft emails so it would support it yes.

Comment: Thanks, will be using the notes method for now. Another problem arose though. Notability doesn't keep the format when it's pasted in... prob gonna just end up screen capping and inserting it into the notes as a pic. Won't be editable, but better than nothing

Comment: As I said, it won't copy the formatting in Pastebot.